# Getting undefined result ShowToastEvent, even so get gives proper value in markup. What's wrong there?

Tags: lightning-web-components, error

```
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id'
import USER_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/User.Name';
import USER_ROLE from '@salesforce/schema/User.UserRole.DeveloperName';
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';


@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: USER_ID,
    fields: [USER_NAME, USER_ROLE]
})
user;

@api
get userName()
{
    return getFieldValue(this.user.data, USER_NAME);
}

@api
get userRole()
{
    return getFieldValue(this.user.data, USER_ROLE);
}


connectedCallback() 
{
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: "test",
        message: String(this.userRole)
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

connectedCallback() is called before the wire method has a chance to execute; it is, in fact, guaranteed to run first even if the wire method has the user data cached. You need to wait until the data has had a chance to load.

```
user;
@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: USER_ID,
    fields: [USER_NAME, USER_ROLE]
})
userWire(result) {
  this.user = result;
  const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
    title: "test",
    message: String(this.userRole)
  });
  this.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```